# How do I just generate data with fscheck?

Tags: f#, fscheck

Is it possible to generate data, specifically a list, with fscheck for use outside of fscheck? I'm unable to debug a situation in fscheck testing where it looks like the comparison results are equal, but fscheck says they are not.

I have this generator for a list of objects. How do I generate a list I can use from this generator?

```
let genListObj min max  = Gen.listOf Arb.generate<obj> |> Gen.suchThat (fun l -> (l.Length >= min) && (l.Length <= max))
```

Comment: Use `Gen.eval`, see http://fscheck.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fd9da99ee77d#FsCheck.Test%2fHelpers.fs . However FsCheck outputs the generated data  for the failing case, so this shouldn't generally be necessary.

Comment: I thought I tried Gen.eval. I'll take another look. Not obvious to me where fsCheck is outputting this data in a property test. Committing some interesting stuff to my public branch and a long message to issue #98 right now.

Comment: By the way, avoid Gen.suchThat. It basically generates random values until some pass the filter, so it can take a long time. For you example, would be better to generate a random length first (using e.g. Gen.choose) then generate a list of that length (using Gen.listOfLength).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Gen.listOfLength. I don't know how I overlooked that.

Comment: Gen.eval expects Random.StdGen. I want to generate data from a Gen I constructed (which works within FsCheck by means of Arb.fromGen) and have access to the actual data for further processing.

Comment: FsCheck is not set up by default to do that, but it's reasonably easy to write a function. I think I could help you better if you post the actual property you're are having problems with - in particular I don't understand "fscheck says they are not" - fscheck does not have any special ideas on equality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: this function is now part of the FsCheck API (Gen.sample) so you don't need the below anymore...

Here is a sample function to generate n samples from a given generator:

```
let sample n gn  = 
   let rec sample i seed samples =
       if i = 0 then samples
       else sample (i-1) (Random.stdSplit seed |> snd) (Gen.eval 1000 seed gn :: samples)
   sample n (Random.newSeed()) []
```

Edit: the 1000 magic number in there represents the size of the generated values. 1000 is pretty big - e.g. sequences will be between 0 and 1000 elements long, and so will strings, for example. If generation takes a long time, you may want to tweak that value (or take it in as a parameter of the function).

Comment: Wow! So far works flawlessly, even on a gen that returns a tuple of my custom data structure and a list. Many thanks.